# FTP: Move all files from one folder to another using Terminal

Tags: curl, ftp, expect

I'm connecting to FTP via Terminal.  Currently transmitting files using CURL, but have also experimented with Expect scripts.

I'm trying to move all the files from one location on the FTP to another location on the same FTP.

I've tried things such as:

```
mput *.* /path/
```

and all sorts of variations but have been unsuccessful.  On top of that, any time I type something incorrect, the server boots me.  So it's been a time consuming process of trial and error.

Not sure it helps, but here is how I upload a file to the server.  I need a similar command to move all files from point a to point b

```
curl -1 --ciphers 'DEFAULT:!DH' -s --disable-epsv \
  --ftp-skip-pasv-ip --ftp-ssl -u $user:$password --upload-file \
  "$filepath$blah" ftp://ftp.site.com/stuff/$date/
```

Can anyone tell me how to move all the files either via CURL or Expect scripting?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`lftp`](http://lftp.tech/) for this:

```
$ lftp user@host
lftp> mirror -R localpath remotepath
```

For non-interactive use you can use `lftp -f scriptfile` or `lftp -c "commnad ..."`.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit arbitrary FTP (and some documented SFTP) commands with curl's [`--quote`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-Q) argument:

```bash
echo 'Test' > test.txt
curl -T test.txt \
    -Q '-mkdir /tmp/folder' \
    -Q '-rename /tmp/test.txt /tmp/ordner/testchen.txt' \
    sftp://localhost/tmp/
```

Commands starting with `+` are executed before the `-T` uploads, commands starting with `-` afterwards. `-*` and `+*` ignore errors (see [Daniel's blog post describing `-Q`](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2020/03/09/curl-ootw-quote))